# Nginx rewriting for pretty URL

Tags: nginx

currently I can land on the join page with URL like this:

```
example.com/join/?number=123
```

it parses the number=... so I want to keep that, but I want to be able to use URL like this:

```
example.com/join/{join-number}
```

I tried this:

```
 location /join/ {
    rewrite ^join/([0-9]+)/?$ /join/?number=$1 break;
}

location /join {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
}
```

and  this:

```
location = /join {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
}

location ~ /join/([0-9]+)$ {
        rewrite ^join/([0-9]+)/?$ /join/?number=$1 break;
}
```

edit:
I've done this and it at least works, client again sees ?number=123 but at least i can go to /join/123

```
location ~ /join/([0-9]+)$ 
{
  return 302 /join/?number=$1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to handle this in your application code? Don't get me wrong, this nginx rewrite method also works, but I think it will be better to handle this in the code.

Comment: If you internally rewrite `/join/123` to `/join/?number=123` to `/index.html`, the client-side app still sees `/join/123` and not `/join/?number=123`. This needs to be handled client-side or with an external redirect.

Comment: how do I setup external redirect?